# Import XML to SQL using C#

Tags: c#, sql, xml, linq-to-sql, linq-to-xml

I know it's not sporting asking for this kind of help,
But I've been really stuck on this for a while - right now I am reading two C# books and working everyday over 9 hours.

Okay here is my problem:
I have a WinForms C# application that is almost complete.
In SQL I have three tables that look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Racuni](
[BROJ] [varchar](12) NULL,
[DATUM] [datetime] NULL,
[TS] [datetime] NULL,
[USER_ID] [int] NULL,
[KASA_ID] [varchar](3) NULL,
[TOTAL] [float] NULL,
[STATUS] [varchar](1) NULL,
[ARH] [varchar](max) NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

Create Table "Rac_Npl" 
( br_rac Char( 12 )
, kasa_id Char( 3 )
, npl_id Integer
, iznos Money);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stavke](
[br_rac] [varchar](12) NULL,
[kasa_id] [char](3) NULL,
[art_id] [int] NULL,
[kol] [float] NULL,
[mpc] [money] NULL,
[ompc] [money] NULL)
```

And I have XML file(s) on local disk for importing these three tables - 
the XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<transaction>
<table name="qryRacuniSmjene">
<fields>
<field name="BROJ" type="1" size="12"/>
<field name="DATUM" type="9" size="0"/>
<field name="TS" type="11" size="0"/>
<field name="USER_ID" type="3" size="0"/>
<field name="KASA_ID" type="1" size="3"/>
<field name="TOTAL" type="8" size="4"/>
<field name="STATUS" type="1" size="1"/>
<field name="ARH" type="16" size="1"/>
</fields>
<data>
<row>
<![CDATA[09-0002-0001]]>
<![CDATA[16.04.2009]]>
<![CDATA[16.04.2009 13:23:27]]>
<![CDATA[1]]>
<![CDATA[001]]>
<![CDATA[2,60]]>
<![CDATA[D]]>
<![CDATA[
   porezni broj: 000000000000
   Zaobilaznica bb
]]>
</row>
<row>
<![CDATA[09-0002-0002]]>
<![CDATA[16.04.2009]]>
<![CDATA[16.04.2009 13:23:27]]>
<![CDATA[1]]>
<![CDATA[001]]>
<![CDATA[2,60]]>
<![CDATA[D]]>
<![CDATA[
   porezni broj: 000000000001
   Zaobilaznica bb
]]>
</row>
</data>
</table>
<table name="qryRac_nplSmjene">
<fields>
<field name="br_rac" type="1" size="12"/>
<field name="kasa_id" type="1" size="3"/>
<field name="npl_id" type="3" size="0"/>
<field name="iznos" type="8" size="4"/>
</fields>
<data>
<row>
<![CDATA[09-0002-0001]]>
<![CDATA[001]]>
<![CDATA[1]]>
<![CDATA[2,60]]>
</row>
<row>
<![CDATA[09-0002-0002]]>
<![CDATA[001]]>
<![CDATA[1]]>
<![CDATA[2,60]]>
</row>
</data>
</table>
<table name="qryStavkeSmjene">
<fields>
<field name="br_rac" type="1" size="12"/>
<field name="kasa_id" type="1" size="3"/>
<field name="art_id" type="3" size="0"/>
<field name="kol" type="6" size="0"/>
<field name="mpc" type="8" size="4"/>
<field name="ompc" type="8" size="4"/>
</fields>
<data>
<row>
<![CDATA[09-0002-0001]]>
<![CDATA[001]]>
<![CDATA[152414]]>
<![CDATA[1,000]]>
<![CDATA[2,60]]>
<![CDATA[2,60]]>
</row>
<row>
<![CDATA[09-0002-0001]]>
<![CDATA[001]]>
<![CDATA[152414]]>
<![CDATA[1,000]]>
<![CDATA[2,60]]>
<![CDATA[2,60]]>
</row>
</data>
</table>
</transaction>
```

Once again I am embarassed to request assistance in this way, but I'll try to suport StackOverflow in any way I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple CDATA elements are not consistantly supported across implementations. For example, you will have problems accessing them an XDocument or via SelectNodes. If you can change the input format that would make things easier.

This code hasn't been tested and there's no error handling or bad data checking, but it should get you started. Investigate using XPathDocument / XPathNavigator for performance and read my inline comments.

```
class XmlCsvImport
{
    public void ImportData(string xmlData, ConnectionStringSettings connectionSettings)
    {
        DbProviderFactory providerFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connectionSettings.ProviderName);

        IDbConnection connection = providerFactory.CreateConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionSettings.ConnectionString;

        // TODO: Begin transaction

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xmlData);

        foreach (XmlNode tableNode in doc.SelectNodes("/transaction/table"))
        {
            IDbCommand command = CreatCommand(connection, tableNode);

            foreach (XmlNode rowNode in tableNode.SelectNodes("data/row"))
            {
                string[] values = GetRowValues(rowNode);

                if (values.Length != command.Parameters.Count)
                {
                    // TODO: Log bad row
                    continue;
                }

                this.FillCommand(command, values);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        // TODO: Commit transaction
    }

    private IDbCommand CreatCommand(IDbConnection connection, XmlNode tableNode)
    {
        string tableName = tableNode.Attributes["name"].Value;

        IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        XmlNodeList fieldNodes = tableNode.SelectNodes("fields/field");

        List<string> fieldNameList = new List<string>(fieldNodes.Count);

        foreach (XmlNode fieldNode in tableNode.SelectNodes("fields/field"))
        {
            string fieldName = fieldNode.Attributes["name"].Value;
            int fieldType = Int32.Parse(fieldNode.Attributes["type"].Value);
            int fieldSize = Int32.Parse(fieldNode.Attributes["size"].Value);

            IDbDataParameter param = command.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = String.Concat("@", fieldNode.Attributes["name"]);
            param.Size = fieldSize;
            param.DbType = (DbType)fieldType; // NOTE: this may not be so easy
            command.Parameters.Add(param);

            fieldNameList.Add(fieldName);
        }

        string[] fieldNames = fieldNameList.ToArray();

        StringBuilder commandBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        commandBuilder.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO [{0}] (", tableName);

        string columnNames = String.Join("], [", fieldNames);
        string paramNames = String.Join(", @", fieldNames);

        command.CommandText = String.Concat(
            "INSERT INTO [", tableName, "] ([",
            columnNames,
            "]) VALUES (@",
            paramNames,
            ")"
            );

        return command;
    }

    private string[] GetRowValues(XmlNode row)
    {
        List<string> values = new List<string>();

        foreach (XmlNode child in row.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (child.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text ||
                child.NodeType == XmlNodeType.CDATA)
            {
                values.Add(child.Value);
            }
        }

        return values.ToArray();
    }

    private void FillCommand(IDbCommand command, string[] values)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            IDbDataParameter param = (IDbDataParameter)command.Parameters[i];
            param.Value = values[i]; // TODO: Convert to correct data type
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an XPathNavigator object to parse the XML, and then use an SqlCommand object to insert the data into the tables. There are lots of code samples for both objects on the Internet.