# how to get data in dataset from xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

This is My XML

```
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Table1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="DepartmentNumber" msdata:ReadOnly="true" msdata:AutoIncrement="true" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="DepartmentName" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="50" />
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
  <NewDataSet xmlns="">
    <Table1 diffgr:id="Table11" msdata:rowOrder="0">
      <DepartmentNumber>1</DepartmentNumber>
      <DepartmentName>Clothing</DepartmentName>
    </Table1>
    <Table1 diffgr:id="Table12" msdata:rowOrder="1">
      <DepartmentNumber>2</DepartmentNumber>
      <DepartmentName>Electronics</DepartmentName>
    </Table1>
    <Table1 diffgr:id="Table13" msdata:rowOrder="2">
      <DepartmentNumber>3</DepartmentNumber>
      <DepartmentName>CellPhones</DepartmentName>
    </Table1>
  </NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
```

Comment: What's the code where you work with your DataSet? What have you tried to do?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894451/import-xml-into-dataset-c-sharp

Comment: Am getting dataset from SOAP service using C#.

Answer (score 1):

Your xml is not valid.  You need to wrap the xml in a single root tag like this

```css
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DataSet>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-

microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Table1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="DepartmentNumber" msdata:ReadOnly="true" msdata:AutoIncrement="true" 

type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="DepartmentName" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="50" />
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-

com:xml-diffgram-v1">
  <NewDataSet xmlns="">
    <Table1 diffgr:id="Table11" msdata:rowOrder="0">
      <DepartmentNumber>1</DepartmentNumber>
      <DepartmentName>Clothing</DepartmentName>
    </Table1>
    <Table1 diffgr:id="Table12" msdata:rowOrder="1">
      <DepartmentNumber>2</DepartmentNumber>
      <DepartmentName>Electronics</DepartmentName>
    </Table1>
    <Table1 diffgr:id="Table13" msdata:rowOrder="2">
      <DepartmentNumber>3</DepartmentNumber>
      <DepartmentName>CellPhones</DepartmentName>
    </Table1>
  </NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
​
```