# Import xml files (3000) into SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008, import

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Import XML to SQL using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772946/import-xml-to-sql-using-c-sharp)

I just downloaded about 3000 XML files from soap web service and I want to import them into SQL Server. Here is an xml:

```
<my:SAP_kis_bil>
  <my:sap_code>2223M2F024153</my:sap_code>
  <my:sap_education>11</my:sap_education>
  <my:sap_kron>no</my:sap_kron>
  <my:sap_miltpos>soldier</my:sap_miltpos>
  <my:sap_miltgroup>2</my:sap_miltgroup>
  <my:sap_miltcat>CA</my:sap_miltcat>
  <my:sap_milttermdate>1970-11-20</my:sap_milttermdate>
  <my:sap_miltstartdate>1979-11-20</my:sap_miltstartdate>
  <my:sap_birthdate>1900-09-20</my:sap_birthdate>
  <my:sap_miltno>HZ 2931559</my:sap_miltno>
</my:SAP_kis_bil>

<my:LG_kis_bil>
  <my:lg_code>2223M2F024153</my:lg_code>
  <my:lg_name>John</my:lg_name>
  <my:lg_birthdate>1900-09-20</my:lg_birthdate>
  <my:lg_miltstatus>TECl</my:lg_miltstatus>
  <my:lg_drivingclass></my:lg_drivingclass>
  <my:lg_mobile1>+82316721233</my:lg_mobile1>
</my:LG_kis_bil>
```

About 3000 xml files like this one. So we have "lg_" and "sap_" and some of them should be sorted in SQL Server as multirow. I already have several sql tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TBL_SAP_XARICI](
    [code] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [orgname_x] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [orgdiv_x] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [orgplace_x] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [orgpos_x] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [orgstartdate_x] [date] NULL,
    [orgenddate_x] [date] NULL,
    [orgendreason_x] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [orgcountry_x] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now I need to realize (import, transfer) this in C# console application. But this is my first experience. Please help to realize application in C# or just "show the way". Thank you.

Comment: So you want to use C# to parse the XML and then load to SQL Server? You have LOTS of options here. You need to add some specifics, this is really open-ended

Comment: Typing your subject line into the search box turned up 57 similar questions. How does your question differ from them?

Comment: Yes, I want parse and load to SQL. Which specifics should I add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps (roughly).

1. Add a web reference to your C# project from Visual Studio (right click web references, add). This will generate all proxy classes to deserialize your xml files.
2. Deserialize your XML files into objects (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he66c7f1.aspx)
3. Persist your objects into the DB (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812(v=vs.80).aspx)

Note that step 1 will also create classes to consume the web service, but you don't really have to use them if you have the output from the SOAP calls already in files.

Comment: To deserialize 3000 xml file into object will I use any loop?